# How to get method result with annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I want to get the result of a method and then enqueue them into ActiveMQ. Hence, I decided to create an annotation(say @Enqueue("My_Queue")) that gets the result and send it to My_Queue.

```
@ResponseBody
@Enqueue("My_Queue")
@RequestMapping("/list")
public MyClass list() {
  return myService.getAll();
}
```

And here is the annotation itself:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Enqueue {

/**
* The Name Of The Queue
*/
String value() default "General_Message_Queue";

}
```

So What should I do to create such an annotation(A-Z please)?

Answer (score 4):

Aspects must be what your looking for. Since you're using Spring, have a look as Spring AOP: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html.

With the advice `@AfterReturning` and the pointcut `@annotation(package.to.Enqueue)`, you'll be able to access the returned value each time a method annotated with `@Enqueue` is called: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-after-returning.

You'll then be able to send it to the queue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write below code snap.

```
 Class aClass = MyClass.class;
 Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof Enqueue ){
        Enqueue myAnnotation = (Enqueue ) annotation;
        if(myAnnotation.name().equals("Enqueue")){
         //do your work
         System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.value());
        }
    }
}
```

**Update :**

> Annotations are not "triggered"... you have to write code that looks for their presence and takes action.
>
> The "code" can either be executed at runtime, but is more commonly executed at compile time using the Annotation Processing Tool to alter the source to inject extra, typically cross-cutting, code appropriate for the annotation.

Reference link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13040933/1326692

**Update :** By seeing your comments it seems that you want something by which dynamically you can do your stuff before your annotation method call. For this you need to create proxy like given below.

**1: MyInterface.java**

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void test();
}
```

**2: Enqueue.java**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Enqueue {

  public String value() default "General_Message_Queue";
}
```

**3. MyClass.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

  @Enqueue
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("Inside test");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    MyInterface test = (MyInterface) getProxyInstance(MyClass.class, MyInterface.class);
    test.test();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public static Object getProxyInstance(Class clazz, Class interfaze) throws IllegalArgumentException,
      InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object proxy =
        Proxy.newProxyInstance(MethodInvocationHandler.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] {interfaze}, new MethodInvocationHandler(clazz.newInstance()));
    return proxy;
  }
}
```

**4: MethodInvocationHandler.java**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
  private Object proxied;

  public MethodInvocationHandler(Object proxied) {
    this.proxied = proxied;
  }

  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    Method m = proxied.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
    if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Enqueue.class)) {

      // do your work here
      System.out.println("Before " + m.getName() + " call..!");

      /** also you can get annotation and access it's properties..! */
      Enqueue annotation = m.getAnnotation(Enqueue.class);
      System.out.println("name: " + annotation.value());

    }

    /** also you can get all the annotations if you want */
    Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
      // do your annotation specific work here like this,
      if (annotation instanceof Enqueue) {
        // do your work here.
      }
    }
    return method.invoke(proxied, args);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: But this process needs to be triggered after each method return.

Comment: Besides, myAnnotation.value() gives us "My_Queue" which is the name of the queue on ActiveMQ that the returned value should be enqueued.

Comment: Thanks, but let me be little more specific. I have hundreds of methods that need to be annotated with such an annotation. they are called with browser and a specific url. every time they've been called, not only the result of the method convert to JSON and return to browser, but also enqueued into ActiveMQ. Therefore, I think your proposed approach does not meet my needs. Am I right? Or I need to be more wise about your answer?

Comment: So far I have found that a class that implements HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler maybe a good solution. But still didn't work for me. :-(

Comment: @Khodabakhsh, Is this helpful to you now?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia things can be happen through a spring-aop. No need to write your own invocation handler if you are using spring.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia absolutely, thank you so much. your answer brought me a good idea. But I'm still working on it and as soon as I get my result of interest, I'll mark it as the answer of the question.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh   If you are satisfy with my answer please upvote

Answer (score 3):

If you are using spring-aop or any third party aop library then you can apply below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class EnqueueServiceMonitor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
            .getLogger(EnqueueServiceMonitor.class);

    public EnqueueServiceMonitor() {
    }

    @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(com.enqeue.annotation.Enqueue) && args(myClass,..)")
    public void doProcess(MyClass myClass,
            Exception ex) {
        //do the code here. This method will call every time whenever your MyClass.list() method will be called.
        //Or other method which have this annotation and return myClass object.
    }
}


@ResponseBody
@Enqueue("My_Queue")
@RequestMapping("/list")
public MyClass list() {
  return myService.getAll();
}
```

If your method have different return type then you have to write more aop advice for specific return type.