# Custom Annotation Over the Spring CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have created custom annotation for stat purposes but it is not triggered when using with CrudRepository as following.

Do you have an advice how to make it possible?

```
@Repository
public interface UserEntryForAuthRepository extends CrudRepository <UserEntryForAuth, String> {

   @Stat(endpoint = EndPoints.ORACLE, method = "get_password")
   @Transactional
   UserEntryForAuth findByUsername(String username);
}


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Stat {
   EndPoints endpoint();
   String method();
}


@Around(value = "@annotation(stat)")
   public Object Stat(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Stat stat) throws Throwable {
      //String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
      StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
      try {
         stopWatch.start();
         // invoke method
         Object returnValue = joinPoint.proceed();
         metricObserver.increment(CounterMetric.ACTION_COUNTER,stat.method(),"success");
         return returnValue;
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         metricObserver.increment(CounterMetric.ACTION_COUNTER,stat.method(),"fail");
         throw e;
      }finally {
         stopWatch.stop();
         //LOGGER.debug("Name: {}, method: {}, elapased:{}",stat.endpoint().name(),stat.method(),stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() );
         metricObserver.observe(SummaryMetric.RESPONSE_TIME, stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis(), stat.endpoint().name(), stat.method());
      }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean _"but it is not triggered when using with CrudRepository"_? Maybe you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13040933/5640649 ?

Comment: What  I mean by "not being triggered" that as  you can see from the above aspect code, which is not invoked when executing findByUsername() method. But same annotation works with different method that of extending CrudRepository. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Try changing the case `@Around(value = "@annotation(Stat)")`